Rendering plotly charts in R shiny App UI
In my mod_page_charts I have two charts as an output TypeA_Chart TypeB_Chart,
In my mod_page_ui have added a filter for charts, where i am attempting to filter charts where the output in tabPanel for  plotlyOutput should show the chart based on chart type selected.
How do i render UI so that the chart changes based on pickerInput selection?
mod_page_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabItem(
    tabName = "chart_page",
    
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12, ),
        
        fluidRow(column(12, tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Value Chart " , fluidRow(
            column(
              2,
              align = "center",
              
              h3("Filter Chart"),
              pickerInput(
                inputId  = ns("selectType"),
                label    = "Select Type to View",
                choices  = c("TypeA", "TypeB"),
                selected = c("TypeA", "TypeB"),
              ),
              
              
              uiOutput(ns("attributePicker"))
            ),
            column(12, tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
              "chart Panel ",
              
              plotlyOutput(ns("TypeA_Chart"),
                           
              plotlyOutput(ns("TypeB_Chart")))
            ))))))))}

mod_page_charts <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  options(scipen = 100, digits = 4)
  
  output$attributePicker <- renderUI({
    if (input$selectType == "TypeA") {
      pickerInput(
        inputId  = ns("selectedTypeA"),
        label    = "Select Category to View",
        choices  = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
        selected = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options  = list(size = 5)
      ) 
      
    } else if (input$selectType == "TypeB") {
      pickerInput(
        inputId  = ns("selectedTypeB"),
        label    = "Select Category to View",
        choices  = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
        selected = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options  = list(size = 5)
      )}})
  
  output$TypeA_Chart <- renderPlotly({
    plt <-  generate_plot_typeA(
      data = datatypeA,
      attributeID = input$selectType,
      x = `Dates`,
      y = `Values`,
      title = "Type-A Chart"
      
      
    )
    
  })
  
  output$TypeB_Chart <- renderPlotly({
    plt <- generate_plot_typeB(
      data = datatypeB,
      attributeID = input$selectType,
      x = `Dates`,
      y = `Values`,
      title = "Type-B Chart"
       
    )})


There's a lot of things going on in your code which I'm not sure is all intentional or not. Since it appears that you only want to show a plot based on a condition, conditionalPanel() might be all you need.
I've stripped it down to its very basics; I've omitted the use of modules and removed the dependency to shinydashboard and shinyWidgets, but it should work the same. Showing a panel does not need anything special from the server component. The app below simply shows the header A is showing and B is showing based on the selected values from the selectInput().
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      label    = 'Select Type to View',
      inputId  = 'selectType',
      choices  = c('TypeA', 'TypeB'),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeA")',
      h1('A is showing')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeB")',
      h1('B is showing')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)

If it's more convenient, you could also consider the use of checkboxes. Nothing about the condition inside conditionalPanel should change.
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = 'selectType',
      label   = 'Select Type to View',
      choices = c('TypeA', 'TypeB')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeA")',
      h1('A is showing')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeB")',
      h1('B is showing')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)

From here, simply replace the h1() with your plot and render it without considering any of the conditions.
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = 'selectType',
      label   = 'Select Type to View',
      choices = c('TypeA', 'TypeB')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeA")',
      plotlyOutput('TypeA_Chart')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeB")',
      plotlyOutput('TypeB_Chart')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # sample data
    data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), group = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE))

    output$TypeA_Chart <- renderPlotly(
      # no conditions needed
      plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~group)
    )

    output$TypeB_Chart <- renderPlotly(
      plot_ly(data, x = ~group, y = ~y, type = 'bar')
    )
  }
)

If you insist on using modules, note that Shiny 1.5.0 introduced a moduleServer() function that should streamline the server function creation part. For conditionalPanel(), you have to also pass in the ns function itself.
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

chartModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = ns('selectType'),
      label   = 'Select Type to View',
      choices = c('TypeA', 'TypeB')
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeA")',
      plotlyOutput(ns('TypeA_Chart')),
      ns = ns
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.selectType.includes("TypeB")',
      plotlyOutput(ns('TypeB_Chart')),
      ns = ns
    )
  )
}

chartModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), group = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE))

      output$TypeA_Chart <- renderPlotly(
        plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~group)
      )

      output$TypeB_Chart <- renderPlotly(
        plot_ly(data, x = ~group, y = ~y, type = 'bar')
      )

    }
  )
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    chartModuleUI('chartModule')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    chartModuleServer('chartModule')
  }
)

